# How to filter resuable workflow in GitHub Actions UI?

Tags: github-actions

I am working on a monorepo in GitHub and using GitHub Actions for CI/CD. Many projects in the repo share same main workflow which triggers a resuable workflow for each project deployment.

The main workflow has logic to find all impacted projects based on the code change.

It works well but I found it is very hard to find each project deployment pipeline from GitHub Actions UI. I can filter the workflow from the dropdown list but resuable workflow is not showing. Is there a way to filter resuable workflow by name on the UI?

[image]

Comment: Is `event:workflow_call` filter not working?

Comment: Regarding filtering by name, you can add some indicator in the name e.g. `resuable_*` to help you in filtering.

Comment: `event:workflow_call` doesn't give me anything. And it is too general. I also need to filter by workflow name.

Comment: @Azeem I can't filter resuable workflow name at all. It only works for main workflow name.

Comment: You are right. Just verified both scenarios. You might want to open a feature request for this.

Comment: The easiest way I see to achieve what you want would be to have a specific workflow for each project in the monorepo, and each of those workflows would use the same reusable workflow. That way, you could filter each project run by using `workflow:workflow-name`.

Comment: @GuiFalourd The problem on your approach is that I have to create many workflows which are triggered when a PR is merged. There would be too many running workflows. I'd like to trigger only one workflow when a PR is merged, which includes many reusable workflows.

Comment: You can run your `pull_request` workflows based on files changed in the pull request ([Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request-workflow-based-on-files-changed-in-a-pull-request)). That way, only the expected workflows will trigger.

Comment: @GuiFalourd My problem relates to how to search reusable workflow. If it is a `pull_request`, then github UI supports filtering it. However, it doesn't support filtering reusable workflow name.

Comment: My suggestion / workaround is to filter by `workflow-name` instead, as you won't be able to filter by using reusable workflow name. I suggest creating a different workflow file for each project path updated in your repo, with all those workflows using the reusable one. That way, you'll be able to filter the workflow executions by project.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Your suggestion works well for single project repo but not for monorepo. The one I have includes 50+ projects. The build is based on `affected` projects rather than everything.